# int inequality as while condition not working in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Im creating a program that asks the user for an integer and checks if it is between two values and and if not, asks the user to try again. Im currently having trouble with the condition for the while loop. I want the program to check if the input number from the user is between 28 and 31 but when i put the inequality in, it acts as if its completely skipping the while loop. [statement on line 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyN95.png) 
Thanks in advance for the help everyone, I've just started learning and want to learn as much as possible. here is the code in text form instead of image form:

```
printf("Enter days in the month (between 28 & 31): ");
int d = get_int();
while ( d<28 && d>31 )
{
    printf("error");
}
printf("how many pennies on the first day? ");
float p = get_float();
```

Comment: Post code in the question as text, not an image or a link to an image.

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not a picture of it.  Also, think about how a number could be both less than 28 and greater than 31.You most likely want to use `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are to do with the while loop is not what the code is actually doing. Based on your description, you want to keep prompting the user to enter number of days until they enter the correct value. However, what your code is currently doing is asking once and then throwing error within the while loop. Perhaps try something like this

```
int d;
 do { 
printf("Enter days in the month (between 28 & 31): ");
 d = get_int();
 }
 while ( d<28 || d>31 );
```

First we declare the variable d.
Then we start a do while loop that will keep running the code within the loop (asking the user to input days in month). If user enters a value that is less than 28 OR greater than 31, the while loop resets and asks the user to enter the value again. If the user enters a valid value, the loop exists and moves to next question.

Comment: Thank you so much! after i got the loop to not always be false (forgot that || was or), i ran into this problem, got caught up trying assign int d a value then re-assign it in the loop, tried to use a pointer and couldnt get it to work. I forgot that i could declare d as an int but not assign it as a value. Sorry, I'm still learning

Answer (score 1):

You are having a wrong logical statement in your while loop condition.

It should be `d<28 || d>31`. You are falsely using the and operator instead of or operator.

Comment: Also, the code would just print `error` over and over since it contains no code to do anything else if the condition in the `while` loop is true.